# How can I install and run a medical app designed for windows server 2008 in Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, windows

I'm currently trying to install a windows server based app that works along with oracle database. This application normally installs folders (as any other) in the root of the system and it's executed in a web browser.

How can I install and execute this app? Perhaps using Wine? Any recommendation or alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experiance with Oracle but if you are trying to run a Windows "*.exe*" file then yes, do use wine for that.

You can install it by typing: `sudo apt-get install wine` then click on the .exe file. Sometimes there are a few issues with fonts which you can download from the Ubuntu Software Centre if you have any issues with it.